# running android script from C program

Tags: android, c, unix, android-source

i am editing atcom ril program so that it will work on my custom device.
after receiving the needed IP i want to raise the interface using these two shell commands in the android terminal:

```
ifconfig ccmni0 <ip> netmask 255.0.0.0 up
ip route add default via <ip>
```

i have created a script called raise_interface.sh which contains the following:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
ifconfig ccmni0 $1 netmask 255.0.0.0 up
ip route add default via $1
echo '$1= ' $1
```

when i exec this script from the android shell ,and entering the IP as a parameter it works very well. however when i try to do the same thing from my C program it doesn't do it.
here is a snippet of the part where i try to do it:

```
sprintf(script_command, "%s %s", "/system/bin/raise_interface.sh",response_str_ip);
ATCOM_LOG("script command is : %s \n",script_command);
int result = system(full_script_command);
```

when running the program i get from the above log

```
script command is : /system/bin/raise_interface.sh "100.96.12.54"
```

running the exact script from the shell works however the System() call always return -1.

can someone help me ?

thank you,

Comment: Is `sprintf(script_command, ....);` vs. `system(full_script_command);` just a typo in your question or may that be the problem?

Comment: yes its just a typo. i am sorry for that. the actual command is system(script_command);

Comment: Is there any related logcat output?

Comment: nothing from logcat. however dmesg shows that sig17 was sent to raise_interface.sh

Comment: Anything in logcat from `avc`?